# Form field values aren't binding to model when hosted on remote server jQuery Mobile MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a slightly odd issue with my jQuery mobile \ MVC app that I've so far been unable to track down.

in my view I have 2 HTML.HiddenFor fields. The values in these fields bind to the properties of my model class in my controller when the form is posted . The properties are of type Double.
On my local dev machine when the form is posted the values bind ok. However when my app is deployed to a remote server the model binding stops working and the only way to get it to work again is to change the property type from Double to string.

Here is my model:-

```
 public class HomeViewModel
{
    public Double Latitude                  { get; set; }   //form value binds locally but does not bind on remote server
    public Double Longitude                 { get; set; }   //form value binds locally but does not bind on remote server
    public string LatitudeStr               { get; set; }   //form value binds 
    public string LongitudeStr              { get; set; }   //form value binds
```

Here is my view:-

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Branches", FormMethod.Post, new { ID = "frmSearch", data_transition = "none" })){       
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Latitude, new { id = "hdnLat" })  
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Longitude, new { id = "hdnLong" })
```

and here is my controller:-

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
    {
```

When I inspect the page after submitting the form I can see that the input-validation-error class has been appended to the hidden elements:

looking at the Post info in Firebug I can see that values were posted.

The above works fine locally but not running from a remote server.

As far as I can see the exact same values are posted back to the server when run locally and remotely

It would be great if someone could shed any light on this

Comment: What part is not working?  Are you able to hit a breakpoint in your Index?  Are you getting 404s?

Comment: The part that is not working is the binding of the field values to the model in the controller. I can see in firebug that values were posted but in the controller the model.Latitude and model.longitude values are null. This only happens when running the app remotely, it works fine and the values bind fine locally

Comment: When you say remote server - you are using the same client to post but the application is not running on the same box any longer?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same client but the the application is deployed to a web server outside the local network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include validators for your hidden fields. Its likely you are getting validations messages that you are unaware of or set your validation summary to display model errors. I had similar problem with float before where the culture on the server conflicted with the client who was using commas as separators and this is probably why its working as a string as it no longer failing while parsing the Double.

Comment: This is just about spot on. The Region and Language on the server was set to Swedish and so the lat\long string values were no longer being converted to Double, the MVC model binding simply ignored the values. When calling the Convert.ToDouble() method and passing in the lat/long values I got a 'input string was in an incorrect format' error. Setting Culture \ UI Culture in .NET Globalization on the site in IIS7.5 to English (United Kingdom) (en-GB) and then calling parseFloat and passing in the lat\long strings in the javascript prior to posting the values to the server fixed it for me